# Coupling between harmonic oscillator and bath?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, thermodynamics, condensed-matter, harmonic-oscillator, open-quantum-systems

I have seen that in many experimental papers dealing with some form of oscillator coupled to a bath, people model system as $H = H_s + H_b +H_{sb}$ with
$$
H_s = \omega_s a^\dagger a, \quad H_b = \sum_n\omega_n b^\dagger_n b_n, \quad H_{sb}= −(a-a^\dagger) \sum_n h_n (b_n −b_n^\dagger).
$$
**I don't understand what $H_{sb}$ physically means or where it comes from.**

I get that it can be rewritten in terms of $\hat{x}$ and $\hat{p}$ like $H_{sb}\sim  \sum_n g_n \hat{p}^s \hat{p}_n^b$ but what does that physically mean?

I'm used to see terms in condensed matter as things like density-density $n_{i}n_{i+1}$ or just plain hopping $c_i^\dagger c_{i+1}$ and so on but nothing like that. So if I expand it is not very illuminating for me:
$$
H_{sb}= −(a-a^\dagger) \sum_n h_n (b_n −b_n^\dagger)= -\sum_n h_n(ab_n-ab_n^\dagger-a^\dagger b_n+a^\dagger b^\dagger_n),
$$
which kind of amounts to all possible things really, i.e. $ab_n^\dagger$ is like removing an excitation from the system and putting it in the bath, etc.

Can someone shine some light on this?

Comment: References? ...

Comment: One possibility is a dipole Hamiltonian, where $\hat{V}=-\vec{E}\cdot\vec{d}$, where $\vec{E}$ is the electric field operator---roughly proportional to $\hat{a}-\hat{a}^{\dagger}$---and $\vec{d}$ is the dipole moment of the particle---proportional to the position $\hat{x}$, which roughly goes as $\hat{b}+\hat{b}^{\dagger}$ if the particle is an oscillator. The minus sign is just a phase that can be chosen independently, I believe.

Comment: @march I have been further reading inspired by your answer and indeed it seems like it might be something along those lines. I found the Jaynes-Cummings model, which looks like it contains an interaction term like $H_{sb}$ whose origin is some light-matter interaction as you suggested. It might be worth studying that model then!

Answer (score 4):

> I don't understand what $H_{sb}$ physically means or where it comes from.

This, of course, depends on the specific problem at hand - the nature of the bath and the type of interaction. An often considered case is electron-phonon interaction, where an electron is coupled to the (polar) phonon field via something like
$$
H_{int}=-e\mathbf{r}\cdot\mathbf{E}(\mathbf{r}).
$$
Polar phonons correspond to the polarization (i.e., electric field/dipole moment) induced when two atoms in a unit cell of a crystal a displaced from their equilibrium positions. When quantizing the phonon field, the displacement is then treated as the momentum of the oscillator, that is
$$
\mathbf{E}(\mathbf{r})\propto\sum_{\mathbf{k}}\lambda_\mathbf{k}\left(b_\mathbf{k}^\dagger e^{i\mathbf{k}\mathbf{r}} - b_{-\mathbf{k}}e^{-i\mathbf{k}\mathbf{r}}\right)
$$
or something of the kind.

Likewise, if we consider an electron in a harmonic oscillator, its position operator is replace by something like $a^\dagger \pm a$.

There many different types of baths that can be modeled as collections of oscillators (at least in linear approximation) - phonons, plasmons, magnons, etc. Another key point to remark in the coupling is that it is assumed to be *linear* (dipole approximation), although more complex cases are possible.

Derivations can be found in many solid state and/or many-body texts: Kittel, Mahan, AGD, etc.

---

**Update**
*Coupling to EM field*
Another commonly occurring case is the coupling of electrons (in atoms or solid state) to electromagnetic field. The minimal coupling Hamiltonian is
$$
H=\frac{1}{2m}\left[\mathbf{p}+\frac{e}{c}\mathbf{A}(\mathbf{r},t)\right]^2-e\varphi(\mathbf{r},t).$$
One often chooses to work in Coulomb gauge, where $\nabla\varphi=0$, so that the Hamiltonian becomes
$$
H=\frac{\mathbf{p}^2}{2m}+\frac{e}{2mc}\left[\mathbf{p}\mathbf{A}(\mathbf{r},t)+\mathbf{A}(\mathbf{r},t)\mathbf{p}\right]+\frac{e^2}{2mc^2}\mathbf{A}^2(\mathbf{r},t),$$
The last term is then neglected, as describing two-photon processes that are unlikely for the energies of interest, whereas $\mathbf{A}(\mathbf{r},t)$ can be assumed to be constant on the scales of atoms or the transition regions of interest in semiconductors (the wave length of might is hundreds of nanometers, whereas a size of atom is several angstroms.)
We then have the coupling part
$$
H_{int}\propto \mathbf{p}\sum_\mathbf{k}\left(b_\mathbf{k}+b_\mathbf{k}^\dagger\right)
$$
(See [Quantization of EM field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantization_of_the_electromagnetic_field#Quantization_of_EM_field).)

*Oscillator raising and lowering operators*
Note that variables $x$ and $p$ in an oscillator Hamiltonian enter in symmetric way (up to coefficients):
$$
H=\frac{\hat{p}^2}{2m}+\frac{m\omega^2\hat{x}^2}{2}.
$$
E.g., in momentum space $\hat{x}=x,\hat{p}=-i\hbar\partial_x$, and the Schrödinger equation takes form
$$\left[\frac{1}{2m}\frac{d^2}{dx^2}+\frac{m\omega^2x^2}{2}\right]\psi(x)=E\psi(x),$$
with the well-known solutions expressed in terms of Hermit polinomials.
In momentum space we have $\hat{x}=i\hbar\partial_p,\hat{p}=p$ and the SE becomes
$$
\left[\frac{m\omega^2}{2}\frac{d^2}{dp^2}+\frac{p^2}{2m}\right]\phi(p)=E\phi(p),$$
which has the solutions expressed in terms of Hermit polinomials of variable $p$.

Likewise, the definitions of raising and lowering operators are interchangeable in terms of momentum and position: traditionally one defines them in such a way that
$$x\propto a+a^\dagger, p\propto a-a^\dagger,$$
but it could as well be
$$x\propto a-a^\dagger, p\propto a+a^\dagger,$$
the difference being the phase factors of the wave functions.

Comment: Thank you for your insight! I'm still wondering why $\hat{x} \sim a^\dagger \pm a$, I get that there is a freedom in the labeling of what $\hat{x}$ and $\hat{p}$ are, after all they are just a basis of sorts. However, in these papers they talk about a non-linear oscillator described by $H_s= \omega a^\dagger a + \sum g_n (a+a^\dagger)^n$ which makes me think that $\hat{x} \propto a+a^\dagger$ and $\hat{p} \propto i (a-a^\dagger)$. This brings us back to my question: it looks like it is a $\hat{p}^s \hat{p}^b$ type of interaction rather than what you described (at least superficially).

Comment: Maybe it might be worth mentioning they consider a matter-light interaction. I.e. they have an oscillator coupled with light (lasers I take).

Comment: @FriendlyLagrangian The Hamiltonian in your question is linear - unless you mean that $h_n$ is not a coefficient but a function? In any case, the generalization is pretty straightforward: if your systems and your bath are oscillators, while the interaction is a non-linear function of their variables, you simply plug the variables into this function: $H_{int}=F(x,E)=F(a+a^\dagger, b-b^\dagger).$ Note that this is already the case in the phonon Hamiltonian as I wrote it (it is non-linear in $\mathbf{r}$), although one often linearizes the exponents.

Comment: I omitted the non-linear interaction for the sake of clarity as it just complicates the question unnecessarily. I only mentioned this in the comment to illustrate that $\hat{x}\propto a+a^\dagger$ and **not** $\hat{x} \propto a-a^\dagger$. This would mean that your $H_{int}=F(x,E)=F(a+a^\dagger,b-b^\dagger)$ is not of the form of my $H_{sb}$ above as the latter is an interaction like $H_{int}=F(a-a^\dagger,b-b^\dagger)=F(p,p)$, coupling momentum of the system with the momentum of the bath. Thus, I am not so convinced this originates from $H_{int}=-e \vec{r}\cdot \vec{E}$. What am I missing?

Comment: @FriendlyLagrangian I don't quite see the difference between using $a+a^\dagger$ vs. $a-a^\dagger$ - it is a matter of how one defines the operators, since oscilator Hamiltonian is symmetric in interchanging momentum and position.

Comment: Sure I understand that freedom in those definitions. However, my point is that $\hat{x}$ and $\hat{p}$ have **already** been chosen as $\hat{x}\propto a+a^\dagger$ and $\hat{p}\propto a-a^\dagger$ as the hamiltonian is an oscillator with $H_s= \omega a^\dagger a + \sum g_n (a+a^\dagger)^n \sim p^2+x^2+\sum_n x^n$. So $\hat{x}$ really is $\propto a+a^\dagger$ and not otherwise. Deciding now to use $\hat{x}\propto a-a^\dagger$  amounts to having 
 $H_s \sim x^2+p^2+\sum_n p^n$ which is not the physical case at hand as far as I understand.

Comment: Regardless of this choice, there is a crucial sign difference between $F(a+a^\dagger,b-b^\dagger)=F(x,p)$ and $F(a-a^\dagger,b-b^\dagger)=F(p,p)$ which won't go away even if $x \mapsto p$ and $p \mapsto x$.

Comment: @FriendlyLagrangian what I mean is that we can always choose $p=a+a^\dagger, x=a-a^\dagger$ - it is a matter of how we define $a$: $a=x+ip$ or $a=p+ix$ (the Hamiltonian is $H=p^2+x^2$ - position and momentum enter on equal footing )

Comment: @FriendlyLagrangian on the other side, you could work in a different gauge and have EM field coupled directly to momentum - e.g., as one does when deriving Kubo formula.